# I am getting parser error by assigning like this in repeater <asp:Label ID="<%#Eval("PropertyId").ToString()%>" runat="server"/>

Tags: asp.net

I am getting parser error by assigning like this in repeater

```
<asp:Label ID="<%#Eval("PropertyId").ToString()%>" runat="server"/>
```

I used single codes( ' ) but Eval  method not working and I removed .ToString() also not working

Comment: Why do you need to assign the `ID` programmatically at all? If i'd need this i'd use the `Init`-event in codebehind. Do you actually want to assign it to the label's `Text` property?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need toString() method.

```
<asp:Label ID='<%#Eval("PropertyId")%>' runat="server"/>
```